# Syncfusion resizable RichTextEditor table popup wrong position when scrolling horizontal

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

When I add a wide table of component 'CreateTable' inside the `React` SyncFusion RichTextEditor (using v20.3.50), bigger than the screen, and click the items within the overflow, the popup menu of the Table (for columns and rows interactions), goes to the right, watching the css of the div, the left value is bigger of what I've scrolled. The first solution was to fix the popup to the middle with a `left: 50% !important` css property but what I would like is that the menu stays in the clicked cell.

```
<RichTextEditorComponent
      style={style}
      value={value}
      iframeSettings={{ enable: true }}
      id="imageRTE"
      ref={setRteObj}
      toolbarSettings={toolbarSettings}
      created={onCreate}
      quickToolbarSettings={quickToolbarSettings}
      enableResize={true}
    >
      <Inject services={[Toolbar, Image, Link, HtmlEditor, Table, Resize, QuickToolbar]} />
</RichTextEditorComponent>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have included the fix for the issue "**Table quick toolbar got misplaced outside the Rich Text Editor when enabling IFrame**" with our patch release version **20.4.43**. So please upgrade your package to the latest to resolve the issue from your end.

**Release Notes**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/release-notes/20.4.43/?type=all#richtexteditor